# UITEXTFIELD input data to alert box ok clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am implementing a user form and getting details from user, after filling all the fields when the user press the SUBMIT button alert box is created (The alert box is kind of Terms and condition) when the user Agree to it. It must take all the `UITextField` input data.

I have created a class and in that class I have stored the values from `textField` and I don't know how to call the class when the user click Agree.

```
func getvalueoftextfield() {
    let UserDestination: String = Choose_Destination.text!
    print(UserDestination)

    let UserDenomination: String = Choose_Denomination.text!
    print(UserDenomination)

    let UserEnteredDenomination: String = manual_denominaton_textfield.text!
    print(UserEnteredDenomination)

    let UserEmail: String = Email_textfield.text!
    print(UserEmail)

    let UserEnteredEmailConfirm: String = confirm_email_validation.text!
    print(UserEnteredEmailConfirm)

    let UserEnteredReceiversName: String = receivers_name_textfirld.text!
    print(UserEnteredReceiversName)

    let UserEnteredSendersName: String = senders_name_textfield.text!
    print(UserEnteredSendersName)

    let UserMessage: String = message_textView.text!
    print(UserMessage)

   // let datacombined: String = " User Name: \(Choose_Destination.text!) \nPassword: \(Choose_Denomination.text!)\n "
}
```

The code for alert box

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Agree", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: getvalueoftextfield))
```

this was not working .Please help me

ENTIRE CONTROLLER FILE

```
//
//  e-GiftsViewController.swift
//  GIFT_VOUCHER
//
//  Created by cbazaar R&D IT Infra on 23/06/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 cbazaar R&D IT Infra. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class e_GiftsViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var paynow_button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Error_label: UILabel!
    // outlet for destination of user
    @IBOutlet weak var Choose_Destination: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var scroll: UIScrollView!
    // outlet for denomination
    @IBOutlet weak var Choose_Denomination: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var message_textView: UITextView!


    @IBOutlet weak var receivers_name_textfirld: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var senders_name_textfield: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var manual_denominaton_textfield: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var Email_textfield: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var confirm_email_validation: UITextField!

    //Contents for picker view
    var Destination_receiver = [["India"],["Europe","Australia","New Zealand","USA & Rest of the World"]]

    var denomination = [[" Rs.500","Rs.1000","Rs.1500","Rs.2000","Rs.2500","Rs.3000","Rs.3500","Rs.4000","Rs.4500","Rs.5000"],
                                ["100","150","200","250","300","350","400","450","500"]]

  //  var denomination_rest = ["100","150","200","250","300","350","400","450","500"]

    //picker view
    let destination_pickerview = UIPickerView()
    let denomination_picerview = UIPickerView()


  //  var x = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Error_label.isHidden = true

        //delegate for Manual denomination selection
        manual_denominaton_textfield.delegate = self

       // message_textView.delegate = self

//        destination_pickerview.tag = 0
//        denomination_picerview.tag = 1

        destination_pickerview.delegate = self
        destination_pickerview.dataSource = self

        denomination_picerview.delegate = self
        denomination_picerview.dataSource = self


        create_toolbar()




        // Destination of receivers modification
        Choose_Destination.inputView = destination_pickerview
        Choose_Destination.placeholder = "Select Destination"

        // Denomination Amount from receiver's inputview and modifications
        Choose_Denomination.inputView = denomination_picerview
        Choose_Denomination.placeholder = "Select Gift Amount"

        // Enter Denomination Textfield placeholder
        manual_denominaton_textfield.placeholder = "Enter Denomination Amount"

        //Enter receivers name place holder
        receivers_name_textfirld.placeholder = "Enter Receivers Name"

        //Enter Senders Name
        senders_name_textfield.placeholder = "Enter Senders Name"

        // Email placeholder
        Email_textfield.placeholder = "Enter Receiver's Email"

        //Confirm Email placeholder
        confirm_email_validation.placeholder = "Confirm Receiver's Email"


        //Pay Now button changing

        paynow_button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        //paynow_button.layer.cornerRadius = paynow_button.frame.height / 2
        paynow_button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        paynow_button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 8/255, blue: 129/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        //paynow_button.layer.shadowRadius = 10
       // paynow_button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        //paynow_button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)

        paynow_button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        paynow_button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)


        // uitxtfield design
        Choose_Destination.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        Choose_Destination.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 8/255, blue: 129/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        Choose_Destination.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        Choose_Destination.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        Choose_Destination.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)


        Choose_Denomination.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 8/255, blue: 129/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        Choose_Denomination.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        Choose_Denomination.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2


        manual_denominaton_textfield.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 8/255, blue: 129/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        manual_denominaton_textfield.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        manual_denominaton_textfield.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2


        Email_textfield.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 8/255, blue: 129/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        Email_textfield.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        Email_textfield.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2


        confirm_email_validation.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 8/255, blue: 129/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        confirm_email_validation.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        confirm_email_validation.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2


        receivers_name_textfirld.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 8/255, blue: 129/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        receivers_name_textfirld.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        receivers_name_textfirld.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2

        senders_name_textfield.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 8/255, blue: 129/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        senders_name_textfield.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        senders_name_textfield.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2


        message_textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 8/255, blue: 129/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        message_textView.layer.borderWidth = 1

//        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
//        let newViewController =   storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "egiftvoucher") as! e_GiftsViewController
//        let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: newViewController)
//        self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)


        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(goToViewController(_:)))

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton




    }

    @objc func goToViewController(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        //write code here to open a view controller

        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let newViewController =   storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gotohome") as! HomeTabController
        let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: newViewController)
        self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }


//    @objc func goToViewController(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
//        for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
//            if controller.isKind(of: ChatVC.self) {
//                self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
//                break
//            } else {
//                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
//            }
//        }
//    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //Number of components in picker View
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    //Number of rows to be in a particular Component
    // Picker View Delegates

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        switch (pickerView){

        case destination_pickerview:

            if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "estoreId") as? NSNumber == 10) {

               // estoreId = 10
                return Destination_receiver[0].count

            }else if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "estoreId") as? NSNumber != 10){

                return Destination_receiver[1].count

            }

        case denomination_picerview:

            if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "estoreId") as? NSNumber == 10) {

                return denomination[0].count


            }else if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "estoreId") as? NSNumber != 10){

                return denomination[1].count

            }

        default:
            break
        }
        return 1
    }

    //Data to be displayed in each and every picker view

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        switch (pickerView){

        case destination_pickerview:

            if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "estoreId") as? NSNumber == 10){

                return Destination_receiver[0][row]

            }else if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "estoreId") as? NSNumber != 10){

                return Destination_receiver[1][row]

            }


        case denomination_picerview:

            if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "estoreId") as? NSNumber == 10){

                return denomination[0][row]

            } else if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "estoreId") as? NSNumber != 10){

                return denomination[1][row]
            }


        default: break
        }

        return "an error occurred"
    }


   // By selecting the data in picker view
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if (pickerView == destination_pickerview) {
           // x = row
            denomination_picerview.reloadAllComponents()

            if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "estoreId") as? NSNumber == 10){

                Choose_Destination.text = Destination_receiver[0][row]

            } else if(globalConstants.prefs.value(forKey: "estoreId") as? NSNumber != 10){

               // Choose_Denomination.text = denomination[1][row]

                Choose_Destination.text = Destination_receiver[1][row]

            }



        }else {

            Choose_Denomination.text = denomination[1][row]

        }

    }

    func getvalueoftextfield() {

        let UserDestination: String = Choose_Destination.text!
        print(UserDestination)

        let UserDenomination: String = Choose_Denomination.text!
        print(UserDenomination)

        let UserEnteredDenomination: String = manual_denominaton_textfield.text!
        print(UserEnteredDenomination)

        let UserEmail: String = Email_textfield.text!
        print(UserEmail)

        let UserEnteredEmailConfirm: String = confirm_email_validation.text!
        print(UserEnteredEmailConfirm)

        let UserEnteredReceiversName: String = receivers_name_textfirld.text!
        print(UserEnteredReceiversName)

        let UserEnteredSendersName: String = senders_name_textfield.text!
        print(UserEnteredSendersName)

        let UserMessage: String = message_textView.text!
        print(UserMessage)

       // let datacombined: String = " User Name: \(Choose_Destination.text!) \nPassword: \(Choose_Denomination.text!)\n "





    }





    // returing keyboard when clicked return
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }


    // keyboard shifting to top when textfield clicked
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        scroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0,y: 550), animated: true)

    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
         scroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0), animated: true)
    }


    func textfield() {

//        if  manual_denominaton_textfield.text != "" || Choose_Denomination.text == "" {
//
//           // Choose_Denomination.isEnabled = false
//            Choose_Denomination.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
//
//
//        } else if manual_denominaton_textfield.text != "" || Choose_Denomination.text != "" {
//
//           Error_label.text = "Enter Denomination and Choose Denomination Cannot have value"
//
//        } else {
//
//            manual_denominaton_textfield.isEnabled = false
//            manual_denominaton_textfield.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
//        }

    }


    //create a toolbar

    func create_toolbar(){

        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.barStyle = .default
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        //done button creation

        let donebuttontoolbar = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain
            , target: self, action: #selector(doneclick))

        let spacebutton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

        let cancelbutton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain
            , target: self, action: #selector(cancelclick))

        toolbar.setItems([donebuttontoolbar ,spacebutton, cancelbutton], animated: false)

        Choose_Denomination.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        Choose_Destination.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    }

    @objc func doneclick()
    {
        Choose_Destination.resignFirstResponder()
        Choose_Denomination.resignFirstResponder()

    }

    @objc func cancelclick()
    {
        Choose_Destination.text = ""
        Choose_Destination.resignFirstResponder()
        Choose_Denomination.text = ""
        Choose_Denomination.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    // MESSAGE TEXTFIELD limit characters
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        let currentText = message_textView.text as NSString
        let updatedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
        return updatedText.utf8CString.count <= 300
    }

    func isValidEmail(emailID:String) -> Bool {
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"
        let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
        return emailTest.evaluate(with: emailID)
    }




    @IBAction func Submit_Button(_ sender: Any) {

        Error_label.isHidden = true
        textfield()
        view.endEditing(true)

        guard let email = Email_textfield.text, Email_textfield.text?.utf8CString.count != 0 || Email_textfield.text == "" else {
            Error_label.isHidden = false
            Error_label.text = "Please enter your email"
            return
        }

        if receivers_name_textfirld.text == "" || senders_name_textfield.text == "" {
            Error_label.isHidden = false
            Error_label.text = "Receiver and Sender name cannot be empty"
        }   else if message_textView.text == "" {
            Error_label.isHidden = false
            Error_label.text = "Message Value Cannot be Empty"
        }
        else{
            let alert = UIAlertController (title: "Terms and Condition", message: "\nThe gift voucher being gifted can only be redeemed only at Cbazaar\n  \nThis is non - transferrable.\n  \n This Gift voucher will be added as a store credit to the recipient.\n \nYou may use the store credit in multiple transaction to realize its full value.\n \nNo cash refund, in part or full will be made against this gift voucher.\n \nIf purchase value exceeds the value of gift voucher, differential value can be paid by other means.\n \nUsage shall be administered by the program rules established by Net Avenue Technologies Pvt Ltd.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Disagree", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Agree", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))





            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }


        if isValidEmail(emailID: email) == false {
            Error_label.isHidden = false
            Error_label.text = "Please Enter Valid Email Address"
        }
        else if confirm_email_validation.text == "" {
            Error_label.isHidden = false
            Error_label.text = " Confirm Email Cannot be Empty"
        }
        else if confirm_email_validation.text != Email_textfield.text{
            Error_label.isHidden = false
            Error_label.text = "Confirm Email Cannot be different"
        }
        else if confirm_email_validation.text == Email_textfield.text {
            print("email entered correctly")
        }

        if Choose_Denomination.text == "" && manual_denominaton_textfield.text != ""{

            Choose_Denomination.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        } else if manual_denominaton_textfield.text == "" && Choose_Denomination.text != ""{

            manual_denominaton_textfield.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        } else if manual_denominaton_textfield.text != "" && Choose_Denomination.text != ""{

            Error_label.text = "Choose Denomination and Enter Denomination both Cannot have value"
        }

        if Choose_Destination.text == "" {
            Error_label.isHidden = false
            Error_label.text = "Choose Destination of Receiver"
        } else if Choose_Denomination.text == "" && manual_denominaton_textfield.text == "" {
            Error_label.isHidden = false
            Error_label.text = "Choose Denomination or Enter Denomination"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please let me know what you want to perform @Karthick TM

Comment: I just need to print all the 'uitextfield' user entered data,when the user agree the terms and condition in alert box

Comment: can you provide complete controller file @Karthick TM

Comment: @VinodKumar Entire controller file is attached above please go through it and give me solution

Comment: where you store the data @Karthick TM

Comment: if possible can you provide with demo project then i will let you know where is mistake. @Karthick TM

Comment: it was working fine Vinod Kumar I will be sending the data to API where each and every textfield data will be stored there. My wrk is to send the data to the api. I have done that

Comment: @KarthickTM, If answer helps you then you can UPVote it. thanks

Comment: @vinodkumar I got one more constrain, when I click agree it should get the value of textfield and also it should move to another view controller. Is possible to write a view controller storyboard opening code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is fine, only need to do a little changes.You need to return Combined string from this method.

Update below method.

```
func getvalueoftextfield() -> String {
    let UserDestination: String = Choose_Destination.text!
    print(UserDestination)

    let UserDenomination: String = Choose_Denomination.text!
    print(UserDenomination)

    let UserEnteredDenomination: String = manual_denominaton_textfield.text!
    print(UserEnteredDenomination)

    let UserEmail: String = Email_textfield.text!
    print(UserEmail)

    let UserEnteredEmailConfirm: String = confirm_email_validation.text!
    print(UserEnteredEmailConfirm)

    let UserEnteredReceiversName: String = receivers_name_textfirld.text!
    print(UserEnteredReceiversName)

    let UserEnteredSendersName: String = senders_name_textfield.text!
    print(UserEnteredSendersName)

    let UserMessage: String = message_textView.text!
    print(UserMessage)

    let datacombined = String(format: "%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@", UserDestination, UserDenomination, UserEnteredDenomination, UserEmail, UserEnteredEmailConfirm, UserEnteredReceiversName, UserEnteredSendersName, UserMessage
    )

    return datacombined
}
```

Show `UIAlertController` like this.

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Agree", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: self.getvalueoftextfield()))
```

OR

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: AppName, message: self.getvalueoftextfield(), preferredStyle: .alert)
let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

}

alertController.addAction(OKAction)
self.navigationController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

The order should be.

1. After clicking on submit, store all the values of the text fields.
2. Create an alert box and ask the user to agree to all the terms and conditions.
3. If he accepts, use the data else do not.

or replace your Submit_Button with this code

```
@IBAction func Submit_Button(_ sender: Any) {

Error_label.isHidden = true
textfield()
view.endEditing(true)

guard let email = Email_textfield.text, Email_textfield.text?.utf8CString.count != 0 || Email_textfield.text == "" else {
    Error_label.isHidden = false
    Error_label.text = "Please enter your email"
    return
}

if receivers_name_textfirld.text == "" || senders_name_textfield.text == "" {
    Error_label.isHidden = false
    Error_label.text = "Receiver and Sender name cannot be empty"
}   else if message_textView.text == "" {
    Error_label.isHidden = false
    Error_label.text = "Message Value Cannot be Empty"
}
else{
    let alert = UIAlertController (title: "Terms and Condition", message: "\nThe gift voucher being gifted can only be redeemed only at Cbazaar\n  \nThis is non - transferrable.\n  \n This Gift voucher will be added as a store credit to the recipient.\n \nYou may use the store credit in multiple transaction to realize its full value.\n \nNo cash refund, in part or full will be made against this gift voucher.\n \nIf purchase value exceeds the value of gift voucher, differential value can be paid by other means.\n \nUsage shall be administered by the program rules established by Net Avenue Technologies Pvt Ltd.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Disagree", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Agree", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: self.getvalueoftextfield()))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

if isValidEmail(emailID: email) == false {
    Error_label.isHidden = false
    Error_label.text = "Please Enter Valid Email Address"
}
else if confirm_email_validation.text == "" {
    Error_label.isHidden = false
    Error_label.text = " Confirm Email Cannot be Empty"
}
else if confirm_email_validation.text != Email_textfield.text{
    Error_label.isHidden = false
    Error_label.text = "Confirm Email Cannot be different"
}
else if confirm_email_validation.text == Email_textfield.text {
    print("email entered correctly")
}



if Choose_Denomination.text == "" && manual_denominaton_textfield.text != ""{

    Choose_Denomination.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

} else if manual_denominaton_textfield.text == "" && Choose_Denomination.text != ""{

    manual_denominaton_textfield.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

}else if manual_denominaton_textfield.text != "" && Choose_Denomination.text != ""{

    Error_label.text = "Choose Denomination and Enter Denomination both Cannot have value"
}





if Choose_Destination.text == "" {
    Error_label.isHidden = false
    Error_label.text = "Choose Destination of Receiver"
}

else if Choose_Denomination.text == "" && manual_denominaton_textfield.text == "" {
    Error_label.isHidden = false
    Error_label.text = "Choose Denomination or Enter Denomination"
}
}
```